# Use event listener with context from other class android

Tags: android, methods, searchview, event-listener

I'm trying to use this `Searchview` Class that gets executed when the `searchview` collapses or expands. Since I'm relatively new to programming, I don't really understand how to use the `searchview` class in my `MainActivity` class. I have tried this, but the following `Toast` didn't get shown:

*MainActivity.java:*

```
MySearchView mySearchView = new MySearchView(searchView.getContext());  // I think the problem is in this line...

        mySearchView.setOnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener(new MySearchView.OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchViewCollapsed() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YES, IT'S WORKING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

*MySearchView.java:*

```
 public class MySearchView extends SearchView {
    
        OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener;
        OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener;
    
        public MySearchView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
            if (mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener != null)
                mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener.onSearchViewCollapsed();
            super.onActionViewCollapsed();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActionViewExpanded() {
            if (mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener != null)
                mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener.onSearchViewExpanded();
            super.onActionViewExpanded();
        }
    
        public interface OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener {
            public void onSearchViewCollapsed();
        }
    
        public interface OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener {
            public void onSearchViewExpanded();
        }
    
        public void setOnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener(OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener eventListener) {
            mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener = eventListener;
        }
    
        public void setOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener(OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener eventListener) {
            mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener = eventListener;
        }

}
```

Could somebody help me out ?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it's confusing .. how do you get `searchView` ? and how it is related to `MySearchView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add MySeachView directly into your layout

```
<your.package.name.MySearchView
    android:id="@+id/my_search_view"
...
/>
</your.package.name.MySearchView>
```

and get it by using findViewById(R.id.my_search_view) in your MainActivity.

On this you can set your listener.